# Line bundles on pointless plane cubics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $k$ be a field, let $C\subset\mathbb{P}^2_k$ be a smooth plane cubic.

Suppose $C$ does not admit $k$-rational points, and for every degree-$3$ closed point $P$ in $C$, the Galois closure of $k(P)/k$ has Galois group $S_3$.

Is it necessarily true that $\mathrm{Pic}^0(C)=\{1\}$?

Comment: Perhaps the "generic" curve of genus with two inequivalent embeddings in $\mathbb{P}^2$ will give a counterexample.

Comment: Just curious: are there curves known that satisfy your hypotheses?

Comment: @RP_ I think any cubic that degenerates to a triangle with monodromy $S_3$ will be an example, the degree 3 closed point specialize to a length 3 subscheme on the triangle, with one point on each of the conjugate components or the conjugate nodes.

Comment: @Kapil Thanks! This sounds a very plausible example